# Woocommerce products loop with bootstrap row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, loops, woocommerce

I am stuck, can't get this loop to go inside the bootstrap row to get products in 3 columns.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">

<ul class="products">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->

</div>
</div>  <!--fecha row -->
</div> <!--fecha container-->
```

What am I missing here for this to output 3 columns?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend handling the product display via CSS for the various devices rather than using Bootstrap's grid system.

If you're adamant about using the grid system, then you could check out an existing solution here: https://github.com/bassjobsen/woocommerce-twitterbootstrap

Or you can try something like this with your existing code:

```
<div class="products row">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); // todo: you'll need to swap the `<li>` element to `<div>` instead on this template and add the Bootstrap `col-*` classes
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</div><!--/.products-->
```